# Selecting substring for unicode data in PHP

Tags: php, unicode

I am developing a church website in which I am showing the history of the church as brief in the home page. The code I have done is shown below:

```
function getabout($msg)
{
    if (strlen($msg) > 750) 
    {
             $message=substr($msg, 0, strpos($msg, ' ', 750));
    } 
    else 
    {
        $message=$msg;
    }
    $message=$message."...";
    return $message;
}
```

This will work fine if the content is English. But when I tried with unicode language like malayalam, it is displaying characters less than 750.

How can I solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The strlen function is not suited for multibyte strings. Use multibyte functions instead.

In your case use mb_strlen and mb_strpos.

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: does this affect if I add English language.

Comment: This is not language dependant. It is character set dependant. Use UTF8 for all languages and you will have no problem.